# How to change temp kelvin in celcius with weather data

Tags: javascript, api, vuejs2

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      api_key: '==REDACTED==',
       url_base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid={API key}',
       query: '',
       weather: {}
    }
  },
```

Comment: kelvin to celcius ... subtract 273.15

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `units` query parameter to `metric`

Ex:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&units=metric&appid={API key}
```

As mentioned in documentation.

> units optional    standard, metric, imperial. When you do not use the units parameter, format is standard by default.
> Temperature is available in Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin units.

> For temperature in Fahrenheit use units=imperial
> For temperature in Celsius use units=metric
> Temperature in Kelvin is used by default, no need to use units parameter in API call
> List of all API parameters with units openweathermap.org/weather-data

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [API docs](https://openweathermap.org/current#data) you can add `units=metric` to the url and receive the response with celsius values. Other units may change as well, see [here](https://openweathermap.org/weather-data)